# Comparing equality for pthread_t and int input?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

What is the practice on comparing a pthread_t variable to int. I display a list of all thread ids and I take in input from the user specifying which thread to kill, using the id. So how do I compare the input from the user to all of the pthread_t variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the practice on comparing a pthread_t variable to int.

You don't. The type `pthread_t` is opaque: it need not be an integer. You should instead use the `pid_t` as returned by `gettid`.

Comment: How would a user specify which pthread_t to remove then through stdin.

Comment: @Kobi Why does a number matter ? What difference does it make if the user says "3" or "9" ? Long story short: *why* does the user kill the thread ?

Comment: You *can't* even kill individual threads. If you think you can, you really need to read the documentation before you try writing a multi-threaded program...